# Electron Application Crashing on Startup for Certain Users, Unable to Reproduce

Tags: electron, electron-packager

We have an application developed using Electron. Recently, we received reports from several users that the application crashes immediately upon startup. However, we're having trouble reproducing this issue on our end. We've tested the application on multiple versions of Windows but it seems to work fine.

This issue seems to be happening right at the startup phase, but without any traceable logs, we are finding it difficult to diagnose the problem.

We've run extensive tests internally on various Windows versions, but we were unable to reproduce the problem.

Comment: crashes immediately upon startup.... for the same user every time? You could use `procmon` to monitor what the electron app was doing when it crashed but be warned it's very busy and may not work in later versions of windows

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. We've considered using Procmon to analyze the issue, but there are a couple of constraints:
The technical complexity: Our users may not be technically inclined to run Procmon and analyze its output. It could be overwhelming due to the amount of data it produces.
Remote assistance: In our case, we are unable to assist users remotely in using this tool due to certain limitations.

Comment: ProcMon is not a tool for end users. You won't be able to get end users to troubleshoot your application crash. You'll need someone technical actiuvely debugging. You should probably update your question with some of this context / constraints